# JQuery setting checked radio button not working in IE10

Tags: jquery, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

This code is working fine in Chrome, but in IE it does not check the radio button with the value=1

```
function RebalanceProspectDisabled(){
    var x = $(".ProspectRebalanceType input:radio:checked").val();
    if(x == 0){
        $("input[name=ProspectRebalanceType][value=1]").attr("checked","checked");
        $("#modalMessageAlert").dialog("open");
        return false;
    }   
}

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="ProspectRebalanceType" CssClass="ProspectRebalanceType" runat="server" onClick="return RebalanceProspectDisabled();">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Least Amount of Trades" Value="0"  />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Full Rebalance" Value="1" Selected="True" />
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

i just always want the radio button with the value="1" to be checked, and when the user clicks the radio button with a value="0" i'll show my dialog box, but then default back to the radio button with value="1" being selected.

Comment: try `$("input[name=ProspectRebalanceType][value=1]").prop("checked", true);`

Comment: Use `prop("checked",true)` instead of `attr("checked","checked")`

Comment: look this http://jsfiddle.net/LZ7Zt/  work fine in chrome and ie

Comment: in IE, i get "Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'prop'", i had tried that from reading other posts to no avail that's why i made a new post, thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak im working with a radiobutton list not a single checkbox and i am not looking to set the text value i am looking to set the checked property based on the value, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @NickG, sorry for inconvenience. fix still working fine jsfiddle.net/LZ7Zt

Comment: @NickG new link http://jsfiddle.net/LZ7Zt/4/